# Get the nearest higher and lower rows in SQL

Tags: sql-server, union

I'm trying to select the first 5 amounts above 2000 and the first 5 below 2000 and return the data in a single resultset.

```
SELECT TOP 5 * 
FROM   bid 
WHERE  amount >= 2000 
ORDER  BY amount ASC 
UNION
SELECT TOP 5 * 
FROM   bid 
WHERE  amount < 2000 
ORDER  BY amount DESC
```

Looks like this is not how `union` is supposed to be used as I'm getting a runtime error.

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'union'.
```

What's the correct way of writing the desired query?

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you're using, as they differ in details like this.

Comment: The "order by"s are what's getting you; see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715820/how-to-order-by-with-union

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT TOP 5 * 
        FROM   bid 
        WHERE  amount >= 2000 
        ORDER  BY amount ASC) t1 
UNION 
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT TOP 5 * 
        FROM   bid 
        WHERE  amount < 2000 
        ORDER  BY amount DESC) t2
```

You can add additional order to the results:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT * 
        FROM   (SELECT TOP 5 * 
                FROM   bid 
                WHERE  amount >= 2000 
                ORDER  BY amount ASC) t1 
        UNION 
        SELECT * 
        FROM   (SELECT TOP 5 * 
                FROM   bid 
                WHERE  amount < 2000 
                ORDER  BY amount DESC) t2) t3 
ORDER  BY t3.amount
```