# specifying date to order by in union query

Tags: mysql

I'm doing a union of two different tables and ordering by the date column. Shouldn't the union make the two date columns one? It's giving me the error: #1052 - Column 'date' in order clause is ambiguous

Am I missing something here? Here's the query:

```
SELECT comments.*, postid, prayers.date AS date, prayers.type AS type
       FROM comments 
       LEFT JOIN prayers USING (postid) 
       WHERE comments.username = 'hoodleehoo'
       AND comments.new = 1
       AND comments.first = 1
       AND (comments.type = 'prayer' or comments.type = 'answer')
       AND prayers.privacy != 'hidden'
       UNION
       SELECT comments.*, postid, posts.date AS date, comments.type AS type
       FROM comments
       LEFT JOIN posts USING (postid)
       WHERE comments.username = 'hoodleehoo'
       AND comments.new = 1
       AND comments.first = 1
       AND (comments.type = 'post' or comments.type = 'shared')
       ORDER BY date
```

UPDATE:

I guess you can't use "date". That must be a reserved word. I changed date to "date2" and it's working fine. I'm sure I'm not the only one who will run into this!

Comment: you don't need to change column name you can use [date]

Answer (score 1):

For your query to work as it is now the last line should be `ORDER BY posts.date`. And by your question i'm thinking you are actually trying to do this

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT comments.*, postid, prayers.date AS DATE2, prayers.type AS type
               FROM comments 
               LEFT JOIN prayers USING (postid) 
               WHERE comments.username = 'hoodleehoo'
               AND comments.new = 1
               AND comments.first = 1
               AND comments.type = 'prayer'
               AND prayers.privacy != 'hidden'
               UNION
               SELECT comments.*, postid, posts.date AS DATE2, comments.type AS type
               FROM comments
               LEFT JOIN posts USING (postid)
               WHERE comments.username = 'hoodleehoo'
               AND comments.new = 1
               AND comments.first = 1
               AND comments.type != 'prayer')
               ORDER BY DATE2
```

Comment: But it's a union. I need those two date columns to be made into one and order by both of them together.

Comment: I tried doing "as date" on both but it still gave me the same error. I updated the original question with a pasted version of the actual query I'm trying.

Comment: the error came from the last line ORDER BY date cause it need the table `posts` as a prefix

Answer (score 0):

you have to specify tablename with date column

```
ORDER BY tablename.[date]
```

Answer (score 0):

The "ambiguous" messaging is an aliasing issue. 
As for ordering the results of a union. It is answered here: [How to order by with union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715820/how-to-order-by-with-union)

Check Mark Robinson's answer. I think it will suit your needs.