# SQL: How to order a union alphabetically?

Tags: sql

This is a slightly strange use case admittedly, but how do you order the results of a simple union like this alphabetically?

```
select name 
from Reviewer
union
select model
from Car;
```

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715820/how-to-order-by-with-union

Comment: @Jeremy Agreed. When I was researching, that particular question didn't come up, possibly due to my focus on the term 'alphabetical'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ironically, in many databases, your query *would* return the values in alphabetical order.  The sorting is done during the duplicate removal for `union`.

Of course, you can't depend on that.  So, you should include an `order by` clause:

```
select name 
from Reviewer
union
select model
from Car
order by name;
```

The `order by` applies to the complete `union`.  The column name comes from the first subquery.

Comment: Most DBMS I know would use a hashing algorithm to get rid of the duplicates, so no "sorting" would be done.

Comment: Does the 2 aliases in union must be the same? (or at least in SQL Server)

Comment: @Gordon I'm familiar with `order by`, just didn't realise it could be applied in that way across the whole union. Seems somewhat counter intuitive, but very useful all the same.

Comment: @Jonathan it's not really best practice, but you can also use "order by 1" to order by the first field in the resultset.

Answer (score 3):

```
select val
from (
  select name as val 
  from Reviewer

  union

  select model as val
  from Car
) as x
order by val
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to set `alias` and `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT 
  name AS NameModel
FROM Reviewer
UNION
SELECT  
  model AS NameModel
from Car
ORDER BY 
 NameModel;
```

The `ORDER BY` is evaluated after `UNION`.

Comment: The query is not wrong. The two aliases do not need to match. The second one is simply ignored. The names of the columns in a union are only determined by the first select

Comment: In SQL Server, the aliases do not need to match. The data types do, however.

Comment: 10x for the info - I did not know that.

Answer (score 1):

your sql :

```
select name 
from Reviewer
union
select model
from Car;
```

Answer 1 :

```
select name from Reviewer
union
select model from Car
order by name;
```

Answer 2 :

```
select * from
    (select name "id" from Reviewer
    union
    select model from Car) x
order by x.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select val
from (
  select name as val 
  from Reviewer

  union

  select model as val
  from Car
) as x
order by val
```

My answer and above both are same. In SQL, we can write in different ways.

We can also ignore `as` operator.