# Merge multiple columns into one column with multiple rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, union-all

In PostgreSQL, how can I merge multiple columns into one column with multiple rows?

The columns are all boolean, so I want to:

- Filter for true values only
- Replace the true value (`1`) with the name of the column (A, B or C)

I have this table:

```
ID   | A   | B   | C
1      0     1     0
2      1     1     0
3      0     0     1
4      1     0     1
5      1     0     0 
6      0     1     1
```

I want to get this table:

```
ID   | Letter
1      B
2      A
2      B
3      C
4      A
4      C
5      A
6      B
6      C
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
SELECT ID, 'A' as Letter FROM table WHERE A=1
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, 'B' as Letter FROM table WHERE B=1
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, 'C'as Letter FROM table WHERE C=1
ORDER BY ID, Letter
```

Comment: That's not sorted.

Comment: Now only the resultset of the 3rd query is ordered.

Comment: And `'A'`, `'B'`, `'C'` are not under `Letter`.

Comment: The "ORDER BY" clause applies to the entire UNION: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715820/how-to-order-by-with-union

Comment: very nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID,
(CASE 
    WHEN TABLE.A = 1 then 'A' 
    WHEN TABLE.B = 1 then 'B'
    WHEN TABLE.C = 1 then 'C' 
    ELSE NULL END) AS LETTER
from TABLE
```

Comment: If A=1 and B=1 in the same row, your query will return only 1 row with 'A'.

Comment: You're right, i thought there was only one '1' for time

Comment: looks good. but it only gets one from each row even if there are more than one column with 1.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this.

```
 insert into t2 select id, 'A' from t1 where A=1;
 insert into t2 select id, 'B' from t2 where B=1;
 insert into t2 select id, 'C' from t3 where C=1;
```

If you care about the order, then you can do this.

```
insert into t3 select id, letter from t2 order by id, letter;
```

Answer (score 0):

W/o `UNION`

You can use a single query to get the desired output.[`Real time example`](http://rextester.com/OTLU17809)

```
select id
    ,regexp_split_to_table((
            concat_ws(',', case 
                    when a = 0
                        then null
                    else 'a'
                    end, case 
                    when b = 0
                        then null
                    else 'b'
                    end, case 
                    when c = 0
                        then null
                    else 'c'
                    end)
            ), ',') l
from c1;
```

[`regexp_split_to_table() & concat_ws()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER)