# Apply "ORDER BY" on a "UNION" (Mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, union

So, everything is in the title.

I am looking to merge the result of two requests and order the result together (as in, not one after the other).
=> I was thinking of applying a union and ordering them.
It didn't work.

I looked around like here [on Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715820/how-to-order-by-with-union) or here [developpez (!!french website)](https://www.developpez.net/forums/d6568/bases-donnees/langage-sql/probleme-requete-union-order-by/). I've tried the different examples and suggestions, but no success.
It seems from what I read that it's because I am working on Mysql.

Anyway, here are my attempts, and the results.

My original 2 requests:

```
SELECT * FROM user_relation WHERE from_user_id = 1
List item
SELECT * FROM user_relation WHERE to_user_id = 1
```

This result of a list made of the result of the first select (ordered by index key) followed by the result of 2nd select ordered by index key.

Attempt 1:

```
(SELECT * FROM user_relation WHERE from_user_id = 1 ORDER BY trust_degree)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM user_relation WHERE to_user_id = 1 ORDER BY trust_degree)
```

The request ran, but the result was the same as the original request: result of first select (ordered by index key) followed by the results of the second request.

Attempt 2:

```
(SELECT * FROM user_relation WHERE from_user_id = 1 ORDER BY trust_degree)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM user_relation WHERE to_user_id = 1 ORDER BY trust_degree)
ORDER BY trust_degree
```

Request ran, result same as attempt 1, but with a warning in the Mysql logic:
(this type of close has been already analysed (ORDER BY))

Attempt 3:

```
(SELECT * FROM user_relation WHERE from_user_id = 1
UNION
SELECT * FROM user_relation WHERE to_user_id = 1)
ORDER BY trust_degree
```

Did not run, but an error #1064 - syntax error near UNION.

Attempt 4:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
(SELECT * FROM user_relation WHERE from_user_id = 1)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM user_relation WHERE to_user_id = 1)
)
ORDER BY trust_degree
```

Did not run, and a nice list of 6 errors.
Any suggestions?

Comment: how about a simple `OR` ? :)

Comment: Have you tried selecting your unioned results INTO a temp table and then SELECT and ORDER BY from there?

Comment: I am so blond... thx!! :D

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, the OR does no work... cause if I have a user in both column, i don't seem to be able to retrive resutlts without him.

Comment: @Quiche: it will work. Honestly, I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, yes it does run... it is similar to the method offered as a solution but in my case it s not as "helpfull".  wrote "select * " to focus the answers on my issue, but in reallity i have to name 19 indivuals fields.
and remove ' from_user_id' in teh first select, and "to_user_ID" in the second select. 
By doing your method, i end up with the part of both thos column am not interested in.
Of maybe there is a better way to my problem and i don't know it :)

Comment: @Quiche: `AND`, `OR`, parentheses. perhaps you should learn about boolean logic?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
(SELECT * FROM user_relation WHERE from_user_id = 1)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM user_relation WHERE to_user_id = 1)
) AS i
ORDER BY trust_degree
```

You have to assign an alias to your select. But in this case a `UNION` is not necessary and could be replaced by a simple `OR`, as @Karoly Horvath points out in his comment. The resulting query would look like this:

```
SELECT 
 * 
FROM user_relation 
WHERE from_user_id = 1 OR to_user_id = 1 
ORDER BY trust_degree
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked.i did miss the "AS" (still learning :)) 
and... no,  OR does not do it. (I did try it first, even tho i am learning ;))) if a user is present on both side of the relation, he is counted twice. 

The union allow me to avoid manipulating the results once i get them.

Comment: Can you tell me what you want to do exactly? What happens with the data you selected after?

Comment: well, my initial idea at that time was to not do a OR so the ID for which i do the sleect doesn't appear on my result to ease my php afterward. 
But once i get the solution above and applied it, i had to left it. cause for eom reason i can 't explain myself, once reading teh answer  o both slect combien together ... it actually mergeed the result of the two columns in 1 (to_user_id)... even the one from "from_user_id". so... not knowing how the change f column was based on,. and i fixed it by forcing the smaller id of a line pair in the right column.  like (1|2) (3|9) using or!

Answer (score 16):

It is written in the [documentation of `UNION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html):

> To apply `ORDER BY` or `LIMIT` to an individual `SELECT`, place the clause inside the parentheses that enclose the `SELECT`:
>
> ```
> (SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND B=1 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10)
> UNION
> (SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND B=2 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10);
> ```
>
> ...
>
> Use of `ORDER BY` for individual `SELECT` statements implies nothing about the order in which the rows appear in the final result because `UNION` by default produces an unordered set of rows.
>
> ...
>
> To use an `ORDER BY` or `LIMIT` clause to sort or limit the entire `UNION` result, parenthesize the individual `SELECT` statements and place the `ORDER BY` or `LIMIT` after the last one. The following example uses both clauses:
>
> ```
> (SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND B=1)
> UNION
> (SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND B=2)
> ORDER BY a LIMIT 10;
> ```
>
> A statement without parentheses is equivalent to one parenthesized as just shown.

By applying the above information to your query it becomes:

```
(SELECT * FROM user_relation WHERE from_user_id = 1)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM user_relation WHERE to_user_id = 1)
ORDER BY trust_degree
```

Comment: You got my token too...Trying all teh combo, i missed this one, I was sure i tried  (To be honnest, i just took a another look at my post as i was sure to have used that solution. Thx mate

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND B=1
UNION
SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND B=2
ORDER BY 1 LIMIT 10;
```

if you need sort by more fields just add the number of the field, `ORDER BY 1, 2, 3 LIMIT 10;`

Comment: Good and simple solution!

Answer (score -2):

To expand on my comment:

```
SELECT * into #tempTable FROM (
   SELECT * FROM user_relation WHERE from_user_id = 1
   UNION
   SELECT * FROM user_relation WHERE to_user_id = 1
)
as x

SELECT * FROM #tempTable ORDER BY trust_degree
DROP TABLE #temptable
```

Comment: I would strongly advise against creating temporary tables for simple selection queries whenever possible.

Comment: @Plato please explain why?