# MySQL Cancel JOIN on CASE not matched

Tags: mysql, sql, join, case

I have the following query:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, n.other_user, n.notification FROM notifications n
INNER JOIN users u ON
CASE
  WHEN n.user = :me THEN u.id = n.other_user
  WHEN n.other_user = :me THEN u.id = n.user
  ELSE "CANCEL JOIN HERE"
END
```

Say for the query above I have `notification` table like this:

| id | user | other_user | notification |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 2 | Text 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 3 | Text 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 16 | Text 3 |
| 4 | 0 | 0 | Text 4 |
| 5 | 0 | 0 | Text 5 |

Now let's say I am logged in user `2`. Therefore, I want to fetch records with `id` `1, 3, 4, 5`. This is because records `1, 3` have user `2` in both `user` and `other_user` and records `4,5` are for everyone as they are not assigned to any specific user id (as they are `0,0`). Also, when these records are selected they shouldn't be joined to `users` table as there are no users with id `0`. Here, `0` means that notification was sent to each and every user on the site. It's for everyone. Therefore, I also want to cancel joining with `users` table when selecting these records with `0,0`.

Now, my current query (without `ELSE` part) gives me only records `1,3` and ignores records `4,5`. I believe this is because of the `INNER JOIN` used here. But I cannot use any other join. I need inner join. How can I select records `4,5` here as well?

Comment: Skip the case expressions, use regular AND / OR instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a separate query that gets the other records, and combine them with `UNION`

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT u.id, u.name, n.other_user, n.notification FROM notifications n
    INNER JOIN users u ON
    CASE
      WHEN n.user = :me THEN u.id = n.other_user
      WHEN n.other_user = :me THEN u.id = n.user
    END
    
    UNION
    
    SELECT n.user, '', n.other_user, n.notification
    FROM notification n
    WHERE n.user = 0 AND n.other_user = 0
) AS x
ORDER BY x.id
```

Comment: How do I combine `ORDER BY` both of them to give descending ordering for both queries in a structured manner?

Comment: What about the blank `''` in between `n.user` and `n.other_user` ?

Comment: All the queries in a UNION have to return the same number of columns. That's a placeholder for the nonexistent names for these.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43742028/apply-order-by-on-a-union-mysql for how to order the result of a UNION.

Comment: Oh so you mean to say if in first query I have 10 columns so I need to have 10 in second too? Also, the order in which I need to place the blank quotes according to the first query, is that important?

Comment: Of course. UNION simply concatenates the results of the two queries. If you don't have them in the same order, you'll get confusing results because the column name is based on the first query.

Comment: I am getting this error `Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1250 Table 'n' from one of the SELECTs cannot be used in ORDER clause in`

Comment: You can't use aliases from the subquery in the main query.

Comment: Thank you. Now all is good. Learned a lot of things today. Can you explain me one last thing? In your final query `ORDER BY x.id` gives me the required descending order but when I used `ORDER BY x.id DESC` it gave me the ascending order. Why `DESC` is not used here OR why does it give the vice versa results?

Comment: I can't think of any reason why it wouldn't order correctly. What is the datatype of `id`?

Comment: `id` in the notification table? It's `bigint`

Comment: If `users.id` and `notifications.user` are both integers, it should order numerically. But if either of them is a string, the common type will be a string, and it will order lexicographically.

Comment: Lexicographically. That's a new word in my life. But all the tables joined in this have their `id` as `BIGINT` only.

Comment: But we're not using `notifications.id`, we're using `notifications.user` in the second subquery. Is that also BIGINT?

Comment: Yes. That too is `BIGINT`. I kept that because I wanted to be future ready to avoid any collisions from large user base (if I ever achieve that).

Comment: Sometimes MySQL doesn't infer the type of the combine column correctly.

Comment: Hi.. I just noticed a new issue here. The records are not getting sorted in order properly. This issue was there that time too but I had missed noticing it. What should happen is that the records should be sorted like this as per id `5,4,3,1` which means both queries should be returning combined sorting. But it's returning individual sorting for both queries separately. Like it returns `4,5,3,1`. Records `4,5` (ascending order) is coming from 2nd query which should be `5,4` (descending order) and `3,1` (first query gets sorted properly) at the last from 1st query. Can you please check?

Comment: I have raised a question for this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69340399/combined-order-by-of-two-select-queries-using-union

Comment: The ordering happens after everything is combined by the `UNION`.