# Combined ORDER BY of two SELECT queries using UNION

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, sql-order-by, union

How can I get combined order by results retrieved from these two queries joined by a `UNION`?

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, u.gender, n.user, n.other_user, n.type, n.notification, n.membership, n.link, n.created_at, p.photo FROM notifications n
INNER JOIN users u ON
CASE
  WHEN n.user = :me THEN u.id = n.other_user
  WHEN n.other_user = :me THEN u.id = n.user
END
LEFT JOIN photos p ON
CASE
  WHEN n.user = :me THEN p.user = n.other_user AND p.order_index = (SELECT MIN(order_index) FROM photos WHERE user = n.other_user)
  WHEN n.other_user = :me THEN p.user = n.user AND p.order_index = (SELECT MIN(order_index) FROM photos WHERE user = n.user)
END
UNION
SELECT '', '', '', '', '', '', n.notification, n.membership, n.link, n.created_at, '' FROM notifications n WHERE type = 'admin'
```

I want the returned records to be sorted in descending order as per their `id`s. For example, if the records returned from first query are `3,5,4,6,7` and from second query are `2,1,9` then all the records should be combined sorted like this `9,7,6,5,4,3,2,1`.

I have tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(

   *THE WHOLE QUERY ABOVE*

) AS x 
ORDER BY x.id
```

This is not returning correct results. It is sorting the results from first query in descending order `7,6,5,4,3` and results from the 2nd query in ascending order `1,2,9`. They are getting sorted individually instead of getting sorted together. How can I get them sorted combined together for `9,7,6,5,4,3,2,1`.

Comment: Just add `ORDER BY id DESC` at the very end.

Comment: Wait... the second query is producing `''` (empty string) for each `id`. Are you sure this is correct?

Comment: Is `id` a numeric column or a VARCHAR one? If it's a VARCHAR you'll need to post-process it and convert it to a number for the ordering to work as expected.

Comment: @TheImpaler it's datatype is `BIGINT`

Comment: @TheImpaler when you pointed out that second query has `''` in place of `id` that lit up my mind. I went on to replace the first `''` with `n.id`. With this the ordering did change but I still didn't get the correct result. This time it's returning mixed up results. Not in proper descending order as required. Also, after correcting this I even tried using `ORDER BY x.id DESC` but that didn't work either.

Comment: @TheImpaler I just realized that it's also using `id` from `users` table to do the ordering. Maybe that's the reason I am getting incorrect results. I need to order the rows based on `id` from `notifications` table. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: UPDATE: I haven't found the solution to sort by id yet but since both queries have `created_at` in common which is `datetime` and every row has the latest time, I have used it for ordering currently with the newest first. However, it would be better I get an id related solution as it's simpler to catch and auto incrementation assures that it would always be unique and the latest row will always be the + 1 greater number than the previous one and that the id field due to being unique cannot be manipulated which is not the case with datetime field which can be manipulated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add notification id in both the queries and give them aliases as you haven't used aliases in your tables (I guess). Then just order by using the alias of the notification id as answered by "Thorsten Kettner".

```
SELECT u.id as uid, n.id as nid, u.name, u.gender, n.user, n.other_user, n.type, n.notification, n.membership, n.link, n.created_at, p.photo FROM notifications n
INNER JOIN users u ON
CASE
  WHEN n.user = :me THEN u.id = n.other_user
  WHEN n.other_user = :me THEN u.id = n.user
END
LEFT JOIN photos p ON
CASE
  WHEN n.user = :me THEN p.user = n.other_user AND p.order_index = (SELECT MIN(order_index) FROM photos WHERE user = n.other_user)
  WHEN n.other_user = :me THEN p.user = n.user AND p.order_index = (SELECT MIN(order_index) FROM photos WHERE user = n.user)
END
UNION
SELECT '', n.id as nid, '', '', '', '', '', n.notification, n.membership, n.link, n.created_at, '' FROM notifications n WHERE type = 'admin'
ORDER BY nid DESC
```

Comment: I asked a few questions earlier and most of them were answered by you. Always to my rescue ;) Thanks a lot. Worked like a charm :)

Comment: You are welcome :) However, if you take a look properly and give a thought then you will find that you had already solved the answer yourself. You said you used `created_at` field to order correctly right? If you would have observed correctly then you would have seen that `n.created_at` was common in both the queries. Using this, if you would run your brain horses a little you would have realized to try the same with `n.id`. That was your answer! Your right answer was laying beneath your hands you just had to realize it.

Comment: Yes, I did realize it as soon as I saw your answer and I wanted to bang my head against the wall for such an easy thing I didn't get.

Comment: Haha.. lol.. Enjoy yourself :)

Comment: On a side note: This should be `UNION ALL` not `UNION`, because there are no duplicates to remove.

Answer (score 0):

You have already found the issue yourself; you confused user ID and notification ID. So select the two, use alias names that tell which is which and sort:

```
select u.id as user_id, ..., n.id as notification_id, ...
from ...
union all
select ... from ...
order by notification_id;
```

Comment: Your answer does the job 50%. He needs to provide notification id in both the queries to give the accurate result. Let me post a clear answer.

Comment: I won't say your answer was technically wrong but the OP seeks combined result which means he need to order the results from both the query in a mixed up manner but as per ids and not separately for each queries. To give the desired result you need to place the notification id in both the query for a combined sorting.

Comment: @RedStar Entertainment: With a `UNION [ALL]` query you have the same columns in both queries. So of course the second query has the notification_id, too. And the `ORDER BY` clause sorts the whole result from the combined queries.

Comment: I agree with @RedStarEntertainment as his answer did the job. I did try your answer too but that didn't work.