# Sorting a Union query

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I have a pc, laptop and printer table, each of them having a ***price*** and ***model*** field.

I want to create a combined view of ***price*** and ***model*** number from these three tables, sorted by ***price***. I have the following query:

```
SELECT p.model, p.price FROM ( 
  SELECT price, model FROM laptop  
    UNION  
  SELECT price, model  FROM pc 
    UNION 
  SELECT price, model  FROM printer    
 ) 
AS p order by p.price desc
```

Running this query does not sort on *price*, instead it returns the results sorted on *model* number. I checked similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715820/how-to-order-by-with-union), but unable to make my query sort on *price* field.

```
model   price
1121    850.0000
1232    350.0000
1232    400.0000
1232    600.0000
1233    600.0000
1233    950.0000
1233    970.0000
1233    980.0000
1260    350.0000
1276    400.0000
1288    400.0000
1298    1050.0000
1298    700.0000
1298    950.0000
1321    970.0000
1401    150.0000
1408    270.0000
1433    270.0000
1434    290.0000
1750    1200.0000
1752    1150.0000
```

Comment: What is the datatype of `price` ?

Comment: Your query should be ordering by `price`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I guess datatype is not of `numeric` type

Comment: I am basically brushing up my sql skills and working on a problem given here http://sql-ex.ru/learn_exercises.php#answer_ref (question 24).

Comment: For schema refer http://sql-ex.ru/help/select13.php#db_1

Comment: @Pரதீப் . . . Doesn't matter.  `price` is sorted neither numerically nor alphabetically.

Comment: @GordonLinoff That explains why it does not work. The following query too does not give sorted results:::          SELECT model, price from laptop
ORDER BY price DESC

Answer (score 0):

you could order direcly  this way

```
SELECT price, model FROM laptop  
UNION  
SELECT price, model  FROM pc 
UNION 
SELECT price, model  FROM printer 
order by price desc
```

could be you have string so try

```
SELECT price, model FROM laptop  
UNION  
SELECT price, model  FROM pc 
UNION 
SELECT price, model  FROM printer 
order by cast(price AS decimal(10,4)) desc
```

or for the ide you are using

```
select * from ( 
SELECT price, model FROM laptop  
UNION  
SELECT price, model  FROM pc 
UNION 
SELECT price, model  FROM printer  ) t
order by cast(price AS decimal(10,4)) desc
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it did not work. I am basically brushing up my sql skills and working on a problem given here sql-ex.ru/learn_exercises.php#answer_ref (question 24).

Comment: Impossible  .. this is basic sql  ..  are you sure you are using correct data set  and data types ????  anyway answer updated  with cast for decimal

Comment: This is what I get when i run your updated query http://imgur.com/a/2uAEB

Comment: Now the query works, but sorting on price is still broken :( http://imgur.com/a/4kzj3

Comment: .. then you have  some problem in your data  .. or  the data are number and must work thr firts  .. or are string and once converted  should work the sample 2 and 3  ... could be you have some problem with your ide .. try using console  or another sql ide . ..

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I am basically practicing my sql skills on a website, think of topcoder like site but for sql. I am working on one of their practice problems (#24), which I have solved. Now I am trying to come up with a different approach and while working on that, I got this issue. So effectively, I do not have access to IDE or console and can not comment on the data types. I am assuming the price to be of floating type.

Comment: then you can use   http://sqlfiddle.com ..  because the sample provided  by me and by Gordon Linoff  work on mysql console  or mysql TOAD and in sqlfiddle too ..

Comment: In mysql the data type money not exist so you should try with a proper data type  ..  decimal(10,4)  or decimal(10,2)  tipically

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest that you use `union all` rather than `union`.  It has better performance, because it does not incur overhead for removing duplicates.

Second, you can do this by adding `order by`:

```
SELECT price, model FROM laptop  
UNION ALL
SELECT price, model FROM pc 
UNION ALL
SELECT price, model FROM printer    
ORDER BY price DESC;
```

Some databases don't allow `ORDER BY` on union queries.  In that case, a subquery is necessary:

```
SELECT model, price
FROM (SELECT price, model FROM laptop  
      UNION ALL
      SELECT price, model FROM pc 
      UNION ALL
      SELECT price, model FROM printer 
     ) pm   
ORDER BY price DESC;
```

This is essentially the query in your question.  It should do what you intend.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it did not work. I am basically brushing up my sql skills and working on a problem given here sql-ex.ru/learn_exercises.php#answer_ref (question 24).

Comment: `but it did not work` ... this should work; what happens when you run it?  Oh dear, is `price` being stored as text?

Comment: The result set it still sorted on the model number, as I has mentioned in my earlier comment, I am working on a sql problem #24 at http://sql-ex.ru/learn_exercises.php#answer_ref . I have been able to solve the problem, but was trying to sort the result set on price, that's when i got this problem.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  Hopefully not :) It's site for practicing sql.