# Order two parts of a union independently of one another

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
select name from table1 order by name
union
select name from table2 order by name
```

I know I can do this:

```
select name from table1
union
select name from table2 order by name
```

However, I want the names from table1 to appear first.  I have spent the last hour Googling this and I have go nowhere.  For example, I have looked here: [How to order by with union in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715820/how-to-order-by-with-union-in-sql)

Comment: Do you want `UNION` or `UNION ALL`, i.e. are there duplicates you need to remove? If so and a name exists in table 1 and table 2 where do you want that name in your results?

Answer (score 3):

The query needs to be a bit more complicated:

```
select name
from ((select distinct name, 1 as is_1 from table1) 
      union
      (select distinct name, 0 from table2)
     ) n
group by name
order by max(is_1), name;
```

This uses `select distinct` in the subqueries because that can take advantage of an index on `name`.

Comment: Is there a benefit to using a sub query for this instead of just one query like in my example? They both produce the desired result. Just curious if there is something I am not seeing.

Comment: @ChrisAlbert . . . You have to include an extra column in the result set, which the OP does not seem to want.

Comment: @ChrisAlbert This solution will also eliminate duplicate names where our solutions will not.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think you need a table alias for the subquery (before the `group by`).

Answer (score 3):

Add a "sort" field and put the `union` inside a subquery so you can sort *after* the union.

**untested**

```
select a.name
from (
   select name, 1 sort
   from table1

   union all

   select name, 2 sort
   from table2
) a
order by a.sort, a.name
```

I changed it to `union all` to make it clear this approach won't do a `union`.  You could also select the `sort` column if you want to see it.  If you don't want duplicate names, then this approach won't work.

Comment: I was working on the same solution, but you posted first. I cleverly closed the SQL Fiddle without saving it, but this does work, within the noted limitations.

Answer (score 0):

You need another column to sort on. [UNION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) does not allow the individual queries to have an ORDER BY clause.

Adding in a column to sort on before name allows for it to sort the individual result sets. See my example below:

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1 (Name VARCHAR(50))
CREATE TABLE #Table2 (Name VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO #Table1 VALUES ('Bart'), ('Lisa'), ('Maggie')
INSERT INTO #Table2 VALUES ('Chris'), ('Meg'), ('Stewie')

SELECT Name, 0 AS Sort FROM #Table1
UNION
SELECT Name, 1 AS Sort FROM #Table2
ORDER BY Sort, Name
```